# how to get from api file?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

i have one api .
my data in my code has 2 section

```
"Meta Data": {…}
"Time Series (Daily)": {…}
```

i use this code for get json data and use in my chart

```
$.ajax({
    url: urls,        
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
          volume = [],

          dataLength = data.length, // but this code is undefiend
```

how i can get "Time Series (Daily)" values ?
thanks for read may solution

Comment: assuming that both "Meta Data" and "Time Series (Daily)" are keys in an object that is returned, try `console.log(data['Time Series (Daily)'])` and see if that is the data you expect. Otherwise, normalizing the names by either snake or camel-casing them is generally preferred.

Comment: yes i can see values by console.log(data['Time Series (Daily)']) but i cant use data['Time Series (Daily)'].length

Comment: Because you show it as an object too, not an array. Object literals have no length

Answer (score 0):

Given the state of the data you've given us, the correct way to get the data from the API endpoint here is to have

```js
$.ajax({
      url: urls,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(data) {
        debugger;
        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
          volume = [],

          dataLength = data['Time Series (Daily)'].length,
          // rest of variable definitions
      });
```

I would recommend, however, that you take the time to either snake case (`some_property_here`) or camel case (`somePropertyHere`) so that you don't have to use the `data['string with spaces syntax']`